# Large Operators?

Tags: notation, philosophy

Large operators have always seems strange to me, sometimes their meaning is based on the symbol and other times it has no correlation. For instance, the summation (sigma) has no relation to the meaning, while

$\bigcup_{a}^{b} x_a = x_1 \cup x_2 ... x_b$

The big U is just a "summation-like-instance" of the small u. Do all operations have large counterparts?

Comment: $\Sigma$ = S = sum. The little $\cup$ and the big $\bigcup$ mean union, but we don't have a special little symbol for union like we do for addition. Same for $\Pi$ = P = product.

Comment: What do you mean *"the summation (sigma) has no relation to the meaning"*? In what way does
$$\sum$$
lack a connection to the idea of addition, while
$$+$$
is related? They are **both** simply human-created symbols used to denote ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by counterpart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large plus symbol (or product symbol), would graphically look very bad, especially if you try to put indices on it. However large version of circled plus or times, are used: $\bigoplus$, $\bigotimes$.